# Connect to Passwordless Administrator account through RDP

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

There is one account on my PC, "Administrator", without a password.

When I try to connect to it via RDP it says "Unable to log you on because of an account restriction".  I think that is because the account doesn't have a password.

I don't need password for my account. Can I somehow get around this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this registry change you can disable the protection. After reboot you can use RDP even for accounts without password.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
"LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000000
```

I use it in a testing environment. I have not checked if this change causes additional security issues.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get around this is to set a password. Think security: once the computer is accessible by RDP, anybody on the internet could possibly access it, and without a password, this would just be a question of minutes untill your computer would get hacked.